# Filter elements in an array using elements from another array

Tags: typescript

Hello guys i have the following two arrays

```
let categories = [A,B,C,D]
let recommendedCategory = [A,D]

let music = [
 {"name":"House: category: "A" },
 { "name": "Hiphop","category: "C" },
 { "name": "RNB","category: "D" }
 { "name": "Gospel","category: "B" }
]
```

So i want to filter music of the recommended categories, how can i approach it guys? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const recommendedCategories = ['A', 'D'];
const recommended = music.filter(value => recommendedCategories.includes(value.category));
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
const recommendedMusic = music.filter(({category}) => recommendedCategory.includes(category))
```